# Find minimum values in a python 3.3 list

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example:

```
a=[-5,-3,-1,1,3,5]
```

I want to find a negative and a positive minimum.

example:
negative

```
print(min(a)) = -5
```

positive

```
print(min(a)) = 1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For getting minimum negative:

```
min(a)
```

For getting minimum positive:

`min(filter(lambda x:x>0,a))`

Comment: There is no need to import reduce.

Comment: min(a) will give a positive number in case the list contains only positive values

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> a = [-5,-3,-1,1,3,5]
>>> min(el for el in a if el < 0)
-5
>>> min(el for el in a if el > 0)
1
```

Special handling may be required if `a` doesn't contain any negative or any positive values.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [-5,-3,-1,1,3,5]

# First min is actual min, second is based on absolute 
sort = lambda x: [min(x),min([abs(i) for i in x] )]

print(sort(x))
```

```
[-5, 1]

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score -1):

Using functools.reduce

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> a = [-5,-3,-1,2,3,5]
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x if 0 <= x <=y else y if y>=0 else 0, a)
2
>>> min(a)
-5
>>>
```

Note: This will return 0 if there are no numbers >= 0 in the list.

Comment: using `reduce` for functools looks like an overkill =)